# quero concatenar duas string , mas com espaço entre nome e sobrenome

Tags: string

## Exercício 3 - Crie duas strings e concatene as duas em uma terceira string

nome = 'alecio'
sobrenome ='martins'
nome_inteiro = nome + sobrenome 
print(nome_inteiro)
aleciomartins

Answer (score 0):

Só concatenar o espaço entre aspas

```
nome = 'alecio' 
sobrenome ='martins' 
nome_inteiro = nome + " " + sobrenome 
print(nome_inteiro)
```

Answer (score -1):

.Net

```
string nome_inteiro = string.Join(" ",new string[]{"Nome","Sobrenome"})
```